# SharePoint 2010: Web Service to add links to User's Quick Link

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, web-services

I am looking out to build a solution using SharePoint 2010 where in user's can add bookmark to any page.

I thought My Links will be a good place to keep user's bookmark.

Is there a web service in SharePoint 2010 that can help me in adding links to User's Quick Links list?

Regards,
Sudhir

Comment: what do you mean by quick links?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do that but i would recommend you to do it in a different way as that way is ment to be for backwards compatability from 2010 to 2007 as its not ment to be available in the UI for 2010 as its deprecated, For you to have quick links on 2010 means you have migrated from 2007 to 2010. In 2010 quick links are Tags and here is how you can change them:

http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/Blogs/GetThePoint/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=401

dont worry there are other solutions:

the solution below shows you how to make a button bookmark thats made in html within a user control if you want to keep the links :) :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4960026/sharepoint-2010-create-a-bookmark-button-that-adds-a-page-to-your-my-links

another better method below also:

this is a "I like it" button method that utilizes the social tagging method that someone has come up witha solution that you can use :) that would be better:

http://patrickboom.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/using-social-tagging-to-create-a-favorites-web-part/

If this is wrong than can you please explain more indetail what you want to achive. I presume that you want to ADD bookmarks to the current page, NOT add bookmarks of the current page so you can easily get to it?

hope it helps :)